# Search for a string that appears in any file which paths contains a given word in Atom

Tags: search, atom-editor

I'd love to know how to search for a string like `join` on any file in which at any level in the path a given word, `workspace` for example, is present.

So it would match all the following:

- `app/js/workspaces/foo.js`
- `css/project_a/some-workspace-awesome-/bar.js`
- `scripts/open-workspaces.sh`

I tried this with using `*workspace*` (img for reference) however it only finds the last one of the examples given (only matches the file name).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Find -> Find in Project. This returns all paths and references to the keyword.

Comment: I know how to search a word, what I want is to search a word only in certain paths

Comment: Then why not just open the paths you want to search and then do the global search?

Comment: I don't think I get you, I don't know those paths in advance, I want to know thanks to the search results

Comment: Do you see that my screeshot has every single path in the project that contains the word I searched for? I even closed some of them so you could see that they are full paths. I am starting to think I don't understand your questions. You want to search certain paths but you don't know what they are. How are they certain then?